# SQL Server Profiler: The statement has been removed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was handed an SQL Profiler trace of long duration queries. There are a lot that take exactly 15 seconds, but the profiler reports the query text as:

```
--*Statement text is removed ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Under what circumstances would profiler censor the text with the statement:

> Statement text is removed

### In the olden days

In the olden days of SQL Server 2000, if Profiler encountered:

```
SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE UserID = 42
```

it would censor the text into:

```
-- 'password' was found in the text of this event.
-- The text has been replaced with this comment for security reasons.
```

But *that* was removed starting in SQL Server 2005.

---

What can still trigger it today?

Comment: I`m hesitant to put this comment when looking at someone with 88.9k rep but I think you might get a better response [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The rules for sensitive data redaction are more sophisticated than the SQL 2000 days but are still hard-coded and undocumented. Related thread http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134297/deadlock-graph-show-sql-statement-containing-the-phrase-password/.

Comment: just curious did you find the reason?

Comment: @PraveenValavan I never did, no.